# Cant install 7zip on elementary OS 5.1 Hera

Tags: software-installation, release-hera

I have followed this [tutorial](https://snapcraft.io/install/p7zip-desktop/elementary) from **snapcraft.io**

I did the following commands:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install snapd
```

everything works.

but then I did this:

```
sudo snap install p7zip-desktop
```

and I receive an error:

```
error: snap "p7zip-desktop" has "install-snap" change in progress
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This error means that snap is doing something in the background. You can see what is going on by typing the following in the terminal:

```
snap changes
```

If after some time the situation doesn't resolve itself you can abort any of the processes that are listed by typing:

```
sudo snap abort id
```

NOTE:  "id" should be replaced by the number at the beginning of the row of the process you want to abort (e.g. sudo snap abort 123)